# Get value from nested list using lambda operators java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am having a Order entity which contains list of items with in it, from that I need to loop list of orders and each order contains list of items, i need to extract Items alone from that items i need to extract single item quantity
here my code

```
public class order{
    private Integer orderId;
    private String orderNo;
    .
    .
    private List<item> items;
    .
    .
    .
}

public class item{
    private Integer itemId;
    private String itemCode;
    private String itemDescription;
    private BigDecimal cost;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How to iterate this in java8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a:

```
List<Order> list = ...
```

you could `.flatMap()` the nested list(s) of `Item` objects with:

```
List<Item> allItems = list.stream()
                          .map(Order::getItems)
                          .flatMap(List::stream)
                          .distinct()
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is confusing.

If you have a single Order with Items that you need to loop over, it's really easy:

```
Order singleOrder;

singleOrder.getItems().stream()
    .//whatever else you need;
```

If you have a List of Orders, it's still really easy:

```
List<Order> multipleOrders;

multipleOrders.stream()
    .map(Order::getItems)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .//whatever else you need
```